# Get matched Items from DynamoDB, Iterate and build a JSON output in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following table in DynamoDB:

user_folders

```
user_id (hash key)
folder
created
name
```

same user_id can appear several times, as the user can have several folders.

What I want to know is how to read the data using AWS for **.NET** to get **all the items** for a specific user and **how to iterate** through them and **create a key/value JSON output** that look like this (for a specific user hash key, assuming two records for that particular user):

```
[ 
 {album: "1", name: "folder name 1", created: "12-5-2011" },
 {album: "2", name: "folder name 2", created: "13-5-2012" },
]
```

The result should be returns as JSONP via a webservice call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding DynamoDB - you need a `Query` call on the table with hash `user_id`.
This will give you all the items related to that user in a list - [.NET SDK Query API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_DynamoDBv2_AmazonDynamoDBClient_Query.htm).
You can use [this example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStartedDotNetQuery.html).

Re .NET to JSON - use [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json).

Re .NET JSONP  - [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221429/how-can-i-produce-jsonp-from-an-asp-net-web-service-for-cross-domain-calls).