# web service call from javascript

Tags: jquery, json, html, web-services, asp.net-ajax

I am calling a webservice in javascript file using json but web service is called only when both of the .asmx file and javascript file are on my local server **or**  both of the files are uploaded on live server.

but I want to test my webservice which is uploaded on my live server from my local server.

So please tell me the way by which I can test my live webservice from my local server.
Because same web service is working fine when my Javascript file also present on live **but** not working when javascript file is on local and web service is on  live server

Please HELP

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to make request to another domain.

You can try to use **`crossDomain`**  option of jQuery.ajax call.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

you can call the web service which is on same domain beacuse of some Security reasons.u will have to use JSON with padding (JSONP).

Your service has to return jsonp, which is basically javascript code. You need to supply a callback function to the service from your ajax request, and what is returned is the function call.

Example: 1

Ajax Request:

```
    function hello() {

        $.ajax({
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "http://example.example.com/WebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
            data: {}, // example of parameter being passed
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: jsonpCallback,

        });
    }

    function jsonpCallback(json) {
        document.getElementById("result").textContent = JSON.stringify(json);
    }
```

Server-side Code:

```
public void HelloWorld(int projectID,string callback)
{

    String s = "Hello World !!";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    sb.Append(callback + "(");
    sb.Append(js.Serialize(s));
    sb.Append(");");
    Context.Response.Clear();
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    Context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
    Context.Response.End();
}
```

Example:2 [How can I produce JSONP from an ASP.NET web service for cross-domain calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221429/how-can-i-produce-jsonp-from-an-asp-net-web-service-for-cross-domain-calls)