# Calling WCF service with json output from angularjs with windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, wcf, authentication, angularjs-resource

I've got a wcf Service which has a method which send its output in jsonformat. The service is hosted in an https-Environment.

i'm calling it with angularjs-resource:

```
var hrdemo = angular.module('hrdemo', ["ngResource"]);

hrdemo.controller('HrDemoCtrl', function ($scope, hrdbservice) {
    $scope.items = hrdbservice.get({ 'Id': 1 });
    var a = $scope.items.length;
});

hrdemo.factory('hrdbservice', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://hrservice/HrService.svc/:Id', { Id: "@Id" }, { get: { method: 'JSONP' } });
});
```

Angularjs runs in an ASP.Net-Web Application. 
When calling the Service I get something like an xhr-problem.

1) How can i authenticate with my Windows authentication over angularjs
2) What can I do to fix the xhr-problem?

Comment: what is the error ? can you run the webservice from browser by typing the url in address bar?

Comment: the error happens when using the Standard get without the method "JSONP" in the $resource-call, Error: Exception was thrown at line 8473, column 7 in https://localhost:44304/Scripts/angular.js

0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied.

Comment: the Service works when using the browser

Comment: why jsonp? are you doing cross-domain request ?

Comment: Yes, my WCF service is on another machine.

Comment: Then you have to use jsonp? that solve issue # 2, right? for #1, on code server you need to have the IIS App pool identity to be an windows account that have access to the other WCF server (ex: domain account)

Comment: Yes that solves issue #2. Thanks (I was not sure why use jsonp, thanks for that). The Service is hosted in IIS (own hostheader) and the application is used in IIS Express (in development/ localhost). They are both on the same machine but will be on different machines in the future.

Comment: because both are on the same machine the app pool identity can Access the wcf Service.

Comment: Is your WebService capable of producing JSONP ? [Have a look at this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14236513/1540688)

Comment: Yes it can produce jsonp. I played a bit with fiddler and i get an 401. I think all I Need to do is to pass the Windows authentication I got in the application with angularjs to the wcf Service. but i don't know how.

Comment: May the `withCredentials` option is what you are searching for `$http.post(url, {withCredentials: true, ...})`. Also there is a shortcut for performing a JSONP request in AngularJS - `$http.jsonp()` [Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: withcredentials worked. Thanks. If you make your comment an answer i will mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May the withCredentials option is what you are searching for `$http.post(url, {withCredentials: true, ...})`. Also there is a specific shortcut for performing a JSONP request in AngularJS - `$http.jsonp()`

[AngularJS Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)