# c# How to get Directorys of HttpServer (IIS) in UWP

Tags: c#, http, iis, uwp

im new here. Please dont judge me if i did anything wrong :)

I have a IIS Server with many Pictures in it with the Path:

"https://IISserver/pictures/"

under this path are Pictures with names like:

"https://IISserver/pictures/312-33334-4444.jpg"

"https://IISserver/pictures/111-23454-4441.jpg"

I activated Directory Browsing in the web.config of the IIS Server.

Actually im working with

```
httpClient = new httpClient();

HttpResponseMessage message = await httpClient.GetAsync(URL);
```

So all what i want is a list with all dirctorys of this site. Is this possbile? Please help me.

Comment: you can enable and use FTP in IIS

Comment: well is there no other way?

Comment: if you wish to use `DirectoryBrowsing` then you have to write parser to parse list of Folders/Files

Comment: Or you create a JSONP service which returns list of files/folders within a directory

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221429/how-can-i-produce-jsonp-from-an-asp-net-web-service-for-cross-domain-calls

Comment: thank you sir that Looks good, but still, if it possible i Need it without JSON :(

Answer (score 0):

You can create JSON service which returns list of Files and Directories.

PSEUDO CODE

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Test");//Assuming Test is your Folder
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.txt"); //Getting Text files
string str = "";
foreach(FileInfo file in Files )
{
  str = str + ", " + file.Name;
}
```

ref: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/db2972/json-result-in-controller-sample-in-mvc-day-13/

Comment: Im working with UWP. I dont have the Folder "Controller"

Comment: On the server side in IIS you have to create and host ASP.NET application which returns JSON data